# asp:gridview with a list as datasource, which also has a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic-columns

I have a table with closing codes, for example:

Code  Description

CL1   Reason 1

CL2   Reason 2

AF1   After 1 period

AF2   After 2 periods

Also a table with orders. Orders will be imported once a week and the table has, besides the other columns, a column holding the batch date and one holding the closing code. This last one can be NULL when the order isn’t closed or has one of the codes from the first given table.

I want to have a gridview which list per batch the total number of orders, the number of closed orders and per reason the number of orders involved.
Already made a class like this:

```
    public class BatchSales
    {
        public DateTime BatchDate { get; set; }
        public int BatchCount { get; set; }
        public int TotalClosed { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, int> Counters { get; set; }
    }
```

And a method which returns a List of BatchSales.

Defined an asp:gridview in my aspx-page, with AutoGenerateColumns=false. I like to get this filled with 5 columns (batch date, count, closed, CL1, CL2, AF1 and AF2) and per row the relevant data.

In my code behind already added the first 3. My problem is adding the columns based on the dictionary. I’ve the closing codes read in a list and doing this:

```
            foreach (var item in reasons)
            {
                BoundField bf = new BoundField();
                bf.HeaderText = item.Description;
                bf.DataField = "xxxx";
                bf.DataFormatString = "{0:n0}";
                bf.HeaderStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
                bf.ItemStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
                bf.ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
                gvBatch.Columns.Add(bf);
            }
```

What do I need to define for xxxx to get the value from the dictionary? Or isn’t this the right approach?

Comment: see if this can help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/160773/Expandable-Rows-in-GridView

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting is more of a pivot grid. That aside, you need either an item template in the dictionary column that shows your dictionary data as rows (not ideal) or what I would do in this case is just have a button in that column that said something like "Show Details" and either have a modal window pop up with the list of counts or send it to a details page with the list of counts.